# Message can't be edited. Бот не может отредактировать сообщение Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Столкнулся с проблемой: бот не может отредактировать собственное сообщение
часть кода:

```
await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=result[0], text=work, message_id=message_id)
```

`rusult` - достает id чата пользователей

`message_id` - хранит id сообщения

`work` - текст сообщения

код обработчика:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.status_mail)
async def status_mail(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    id = int(message.text)
    status = 0
    db.edit_work_status(id, status)
    ids = db.id_exists()
    work_data = db.work_data(ids)
    for row in work_data:
        work = fmt.text(f"1", fmt.hbold("• Тула:"), f"{row[1]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Адрес:"), f"{row[2]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Что делать:"), f"{row[3]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Начало:"), f"{row[4]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Вам на руки:"), fmt.hunderline(f"{row[5]}"),  "р./час, минималка", fmt.hunderline("2"), "часа")
        method = "HTML"
        message_id = f"{row[8]}"
        results = db.mailling()
        for result in results:
            await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=result[0], text=work, parse_mode=method, message_id=message_id)
        await state.finish()
```

текст ошибки:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-30' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=MessageCantBeEdited("Message can't be edited")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\bt_f\main.py", line 146, in status_closed_mail
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=result[0], text=work, message_id=message_id)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 2411, in edit_message_text
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.EDIT_MESSAGE_TEXT, payload)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited
```

Comment: Текста сообщения отличается от того, на который Вы хотите изменить, или они одинаковы?

Comment: да ,текста отличается

Comment: Покажите весь код Вашего обработчика, такое ощущение, что Вы вовсе не aiogram пользуетесь

Comment: @dp.message_handler(state=Form.status_mail)
async def status_mail(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
 id = int(message.text)
 status = 0
 db.edit_work_status(id, status)
 ids = db.id_exists()
 work_data = db.work_data(ids)
 for row in work_data:
  work = fmt.text(f"1", fmt.hbold("• Тула:"), f"{row[1]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Адрес:"), f"{row[2]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Что делать:"), f"{row[3]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Начало:"), f"{row[4]}\n", fmt.hbold("• Вам на руки:"), fmt.hunderline(f"{row[5]}"),  "р./час, минималка", fmt.hunderline("2"), "часа")

Comment: method = "HTML"
  message_id = f"{row[8]}"
  results = db.mailling()
  for result in results:
   await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=result[0], text=work, parse_mode=method, message_id=message_id)
  await state.finish()

Comment: Код пожалуйста не в комментарии, а в вопрос. Для этого есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1323213/edit)

Comment: готово , отредактировал

Comment: Опишите Вашу задачу, какое конкретно сообщение Вы хотите отредактировать, и зачем Вы беретё айди чата и сообщения из базы?

Comment: через админ панель создается сообщение для рассылки , ему сразу присваивается id сообщения и рассылается всем зарегистрированным пользователям. теперь нужно это сообщение отредактировать у всех пользователей

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из процесса, который Вы описали и Вашего кода, причин ошибки может быть две: не найден чат, или сообщение, которое нужно редактировать.

Вы не можете сами присвоить ID отправляемому сообщению (да и зачем?), так как оно у каждого пользователя уникально и должно генерироваться автоматически.

Костыльное решение проблемы - хранить ВСЕ отправленные сообщения в базе, с их оригинальными ID, и потом уже редактировать конкретные сообщение.

Хорошее решение проблемы - использовать новую рассылку.

Comment: я и храню все отправленные сообщения и их оригинальные значения в базе , нужно именно отредактировать сообщение

Comment: Вы сказали, что Вы создаёте сообщение в админке, и ему присваивается ID, потом Вы ищете сообщение по этому ID, и его, конечно же, нет

Comment: суть вопроса - как отредактировать сообщение используя значения chat_id и message_id из базы

Comment: Дампите chat_id и message_id, которые Вы получаете из базы, и перед этим дампите те, которые были отправлены. Причин тут две, и больше быть не может

Comment: я так и делаю .

Comment: если не находит значение chat_id или message_id, или же значение не корректно - выводит другую ошибку. тут он именно отредактировать не может

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `message_id + 1`. В моём случае сработало. Удалял не нужные сообщения из чата. При вызове команды (допустим `/start`) `message_id = 1`, а ответ бота будет с `message_id = 2`. При добавлении единицы, получаем `message_id` бота.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]